# Triple Integration with Python / Numpy / Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I am new to python and learning by following Python "Scientific lecture notes
Release 2013.1" tutorial.
Please help me solve this triple intergration problem in the srcreenshot below (Pg 70). I have covered the previous content of that tutorial.
Please provide step-wise commands with explanation if possible because being an Aerospace engineer programming concepts are new to me.

Thank You.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50511173/Untitled.png]

Exercise: Crude integral approximations
Write a function f(a, b, c) that returns a^b - c. Form a 24x12x6 array containing its values in parameter
ranges [0,1] x [0,1] x [0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might seem daunting but the question tells you step by step what to do.

Write a function `f(a, b, c)` that returns `a^b-c`.

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return a ** b - c
```

Form a 24x12x6 array containing its parameter ranges `[0,1] x [0,1] x [0,1]`. Gives you the `ogrid` hint. So reading the docs I'm guessing that looks like:

```
x = np.ogrid[0:1:24j, 0:1:12j, 0:1:6j]
```

And you can then do

```
f(x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

And take then take the mean

```
np.mean(f(x[0], x[1], x[2]))
```

Which gives me `0.18884234602967925`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got confused by the usage ogrid function and misunderstood the function. Got it working as follows without the additional axis reference statement: def f(a,b,c):
 return a**b - c ; a,b,c=np.ogrid[0:1:24j,0:1:12j,0:1:6j]  ;  np.mean(f(a,b,c))

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the problem. They aren't asking you to compute the integral. They are asking you to compute the mean of that function over a set of points. The motivation of the exercise is that this mean will be an approximation of the value of that integral.

All you need to do is form the array they request, with 24x12x6 values, sum all of them, and divide by the number of elements in that array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstood the question and tried to implement the scipy intergrate function as I did not understand that ogrid function part. Is it ok to use this method and employ higher descretization (the j value in numpy.ogrid[start:end:j] ) for solving all kinds of such similar integral problems?

Comment: Not always. It will work in this case because you are computing the integral in a unit volume: the volume of the domain of integration [0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1] is 1, that's why the mean value is an approximation of the value of the integral. If your volume is X, you can approximate it by X times the mean.